# Import tables dynamically in Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite

I'm trying to import a large amount of data in my Android app, I'm parsing almost 5-600000 rows from xml file and then import in Sqlite db.

Despite of optimizations I've tried, it's not acceptable to wait for minutes on first launch of the app so I would dynamically insert certain pre-populated tables in the database on the base of user's choice (on the web I've only found how to import an entire database).

Edit:
Example for my case: User selects to download English and Italian dictionaries, I would insert that pre-populated tables without parsing and inserting every single rows of xml files.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the problem with importing a complete database?

Comment: There would be tables that are not interesting for the user

Comment: an empty table should weight almost nothing in terms of bytes, why don't you just populate the most dense tables and leave others empty?

Comment: I want to fill my db with certain pre-populated tables (dictionaries), these tables are selected from users.
I've edited my post with an example

Comment: so, what's the problem in inserting the whole db with all these tables already filled in your app?

Comment: Every dictionary (table + index) is circa 6MB, if n = number of dictionaries the database will be of n * 6 MB

Comment: if you want to download the dictionary and insert it without any parsing process I think you want to directly download the sql insert query already filled with your data